# React passing Drag Events Up; this.props.onDragStart not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am building a chess game using React and have a piece component which is draggable.  When I handle drag events within the component itself I have no problems.  However, when I try to pass drag events up to the parent component for handling, I get the error: TypeError: _this6.props.onDragStart is not a function.

The strangest part is that it seems to work until the error is thrown.  I click the piece to move and and I get alerted with  "starttt" which means that the function in the parent component was called successfully but then I get the error above implying that the function that was just called could not be found.  I am very confused by this.

Here is my code for the parent component and draggable component.

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  drag_start(event) {
    alert('startttt')
  }

  renderSquare(color){
    var class_name = "dark square"
    var url = null;

    if (this.props.value) {
      url = this.props.value.url;
    }
    if (color) {
        class_name = "light square"
    }
    if (url){
      return <div className={class_name} onClick={() => 
    this.props.onClick()} onDragStart = {(event) => this.drag_start(event)} 
     > 
    <ReactPiece url = {url}/> </div>
    }
    else {
      return <div className={class_name} onClick={() => 
      this.props.onClick()} > </div>
    }
  }
  render() {
    var color = this.props.color
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {this.renderSquare(color)}
    </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class ReactPiece extends React.Component {
  dragEnd = (event) => {
    alert('end')
  }
  drop = (event) => {
    alert('drop')
  }
  render() {
    var url = this.props.url
    return <img src={url} width="43" height="43" alt ='' draggable="true" 
    onDragStart={(event) => this.props.onDragStart(event)} onDrop= 
    {this.drop} 
    onDragOver={(event) => event.preventDefault()} onDragEnd={this.dragEnd} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing anything into the `onDragStart` props of ReactPeice

Comment: Oh my god I just realized that after I submitted the question.  Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help!